# Stata: replace content of var's obs 1 with content of var 2's obs 5 based on condition

Tags: replace, conditional-statements, stata

I am looking for help on the following issue using Stata:

If the content of `var1` (say for observation 1) matches the content of `var2` (say for observation 5), then how can one replace a new variable's 1st observation with the content of a `var3`'s 5th observation and do so for all possible values var2 can take on?

I have tried the following:

```
gen new_var==0
 levelsof var2, local(levels)
 foreach l of local levels{
 replace new_var== var3[] if `l'==var1
 }
```

Comment: Although questions should be specific, this is extraordinarily specific and seems most unlikely to be of wider use unless improved. Please make it clearer with context showing why you want this and a data example. The `stata` tag wiki provides very detailed guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
gen wanted = . 
replace wanted = var3[5] in 1 if var1[1] == var2[5]
```

For once, and this is rare in Stata, this is equivalent:

```
if var1[1] == var2[5] replace wanted = var3[5] in 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The observation numbers (1&5) were just for illustrative purposes. (How) is it possible to do the same operation for a GENERAL condition where var1's observation j in 1/n & var2's observation i in 1/n & i!=j?

Comment: Please give a data example. Please also give some context. It seems quite likely that knowing how the problem arises would allow a better answer.